# expo with splash-screen for react-native

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-splash-screen

I am using react-native with expo and splash screen.

I want to use some local fonts, and I encountered problems that probably related to expo version of react-native.

In package.json:

```json
    "dependencies": {
      "expo": "~48.0.15",
      "expo-font": "^11.6.0",
      "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
      "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
      "react": "18.2.0",
      "react-dom": "18.2.0",
      "react-native": "^0.72.6",
      "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
      "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2"
    }
```

I am using `expo-splash-screen`, since `expo-app-loading` is deprecated (also expo need not to install globally - it is not global installed right now).

Also installation for expo:

```
npx expo install <expo-package-name>
```

In code:

```js
    import SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
    export default function App() {
    ...
    async function prepare() {
        try {
            // Keep the splash screen visible while we fetch resources
            console.log("****step 1");
            await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync(); // *** The problem.
            console.log("*****step 2");
            // Pre-load fonts, make any API calls you need to do here
            await Font.loadAsync({
            'openSans': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'),
            'openSansBold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'),
        });
        }
        catch(e) {
        // console.warn(e);
        } finally {
            console.log("*****step 3");
            setAppIsReady(true);
            console.log("*****step 4");
            await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
            console.log("*****step 5");
        }
    }
    prepare();
    }, []);
    if (!appIsReady) {
        return null;
    }
```

...
step 2 never occured ...
So just after, the program:

```js
    await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
```

I got warning:

> TypeError: Cannot read property: 'preventAutoHideAsync' of undefined.

Exception I got:

> Possible Unhandled promose Rejection (id: 0): TypeErrorr: cannot read
> property 'hideAsync' of undefined.

I have IOS. I thought this is an IOS issue, but for android I got the same message as well.

[IOS issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/9286)

**Android emulator exception:**

[image: Android emulator exception]

I did log like this:

```
console.log(SplashScreen);
```

and got as a result: undefined.

As I searched, there may be need to run: `npx pod-install` (i.e. [Pod install recommendation](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8067))

For windows: npx pod-install returns:

> CocoaPods is only supported on darwin machines

Is that the problem? Can it run in windows, anyway?
AFAIK, darwin machines are macos, but when using expo - it should enable this on windows
([running on windows solved by expo](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage/issues/364))

I have an iphone, so my code runs on iphone (but the code is written on windows environment machine).

What may be the fix for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the source - there were few mistakes, maily that:

```
import SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
```

is incorrect, and should be :

```
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
```

The decrlarations for package.json are fine.

Here is a full code with correction, as I realized from [SplashScreen - Expo Documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/)

```
...
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
...
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function prepare() {
      try {
        ...
        await <Promise>; 
        ...
        await Font.loadAsync({
          'open-sans': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'),
          'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'),
        });
        ...

      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
      } finally {
        setAppIsReady(true);  
      }

    prepare();

  }, []);


   
  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (appIsReady) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [appIsReady]);

  if (!appIsReady) {
    return null;
  }



  return (
    <>
      <NavigationContainer onReady={onLayoutRootView}> ...
    </>
  );
}
```

For view (instead of navigation container, there may be change for the readiness state), i.e. :

```
<View onLayoutRootView={onLayoutRootView} > ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to wait for SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync(). Check the docs https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/#usage

There is also a hook from expo-font - useFonts - which returns a boolean to indicate when the fonts are loaded. You can check it out here https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/font/#usage

If you stick to one of the examples I believe you will be ok :)

Comment: I tried that. Not work either. I have IOS - maybe there is an issue for IOS? https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/9286

Comment: In my App.js SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync(); is called in the global scope. Then :
`
export default function App() {
    const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
        'din-pro': require('./assets/fonts/DIN-PRO.ttf')
    });
    const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
        if (fontsLoaded) await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }, [fontsLoaded]);

    if (!fontsLoaded) return null;

    return 
        <View onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
        ...
        </View>
}
`
This works on Android...

Comment: I have tried either as the example w/o any async call.
Just: SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()
Same behaviour. I check on iphone (with usb - real iphone. Not an emulator and noton android). As I mentioned - I don't know whether this is IOS issue. I provided all the versions as for my code.

Comment: One more thing comes to my mind. I think Expo SDK 48 is compatible with RN 0.71, and you have 0.72.
https://reactnative.dev/blog/2023/06/21/0.72-metro-package-exports-symlinks#upgrade-to-072

Comment: I see that after changing version: "expo": "^49.0.16", and react-native: "^0.72.6", I still have the problem.
BTW - For fixes of any versions, I do: npm audit fix --force, so I got the correct versions of packages (by tree).

Comment: Also - Whether I do: 
console.log(SplashScreen);
I got undefined.

Comment: I see that I may need to install pod. but for windows: npx pod-install returns: CocoaPods is only supported on darwin machines
i.e. https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8067

Comment: I have only been using RN for android apps and always with Expo, but from previous research I know that you don't need pod when your project is managed and if it's not you need Xcode, which runs only on macOS (and not on Windows). This may not be 100% true, but I don't think you need CocoaPods anyways

Comment: @Eitan have you been able to fix issue? I'm also getting undefined